# Why won't the controls disappear in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-media-player

Usually when I watch something with Windows Media Player, the controls automatically hide themselves after a few seconds of not touching them.  The last few times, however, they have just stayed on the screen the whole time, which is pretty annoying. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open `Windows Media Player`
2. Press `F10`
3. Go to `Tools > Options`
4. There is a checkbox named `Allow autohide of playback controls` : check it
5. Press `Apply`

Ensure that your mouse is left hovering over the video itself for the controls to hide, its an annoying requirement but if your mouse is on another screen or off the video they won't hide.

Comment: I just learned there is also a shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go to options and go to the performance tab.

There go to the bottom where it says "DVD and Video playback".

Un-check "Display full screen controls".

Comment: To me Jason Bristol's checkbox was already checked. This should be the accepted answer.